# TIPC socket types in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tipc

When using in Linux a TIPC socket, when should I use TIPC_ADDR_ID, TIPC_ADDR_NAME, TIPC_ADDR_NAMESEQ.
Can someone tell what is the different between them? 
What are the benefits of each address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be explained fairly clearly in a comment added in this patch: http://blitiri.com.ar/git/r/pytipc/c/15cae2455c1774400949069e98b3abf5ea20e311/

Namely:

```
+Addresses are expressed as (addr_type, v1, v2, v3 [, scope]);
+where addr_type can be one of:
+   TIPC_ADDR_NAMESEQ, TIPC_ADDR_MCAST, TIPC_ADDR_NAME, and TIPC_ADDR_ID;
+and scope can be one of:
+   TIPC_ZONE_SCOPE, TIPC_CLUSTER_SCOPE, and TIPC_NODE_SCOPE.
+
+
+The meaning of v1, v2 and v3 depend on the value of addr_type:
+
+   if addr_type is TIPC_ADDR_NAME:
+       v1 is the server type
+       v2 is the port identifier
+       v3 is ignored
+   if addr_type is TIPC_ADDR_NAMESEQ or TIPC_ADDR_MCAST:
+       v1 is the server type
+       v2 is the lower port number
+       v3 is the upper port number
+   if addr_type is TIPC_ADDR_ID:
+       v1 is the node
+       v2 is the ref
+       v3 is ignored
+
+Even when ignored, v3 must be present and be an integer.
```